# X509Certificate2.Verify() behaviour first time usage

Tags: c#, dll, certificate, x509certificate, x509certificate2

Im working on a test were I use certificates. I have the following code were I check .dll's in a folder and see if they have a certificate. If they do and they are verified, I add them to an assemblies list:

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory, "*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (var file in files)
{
   try
   {
       var cert = new X509Certificate2(X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile(file));
       if (cert.IsNull() || !cert.Verify() || !PUBLIC_KEY.Equals(cert.GetPublicKeyString()))
       {
          cert.Dispose();
          continue;
       }

       cert.Dispose();

       assemblies.Add(Assembly.LoadFrom(file));
   }
   catch (CryptographicException)
   {
     // dll not signed
   }
}
```

But the strange thing is if the pc is not connected to the internet, it will not add the .dll's to my assemblies. But if its connected to the internet and I run my test, all dll's with the certificate are added to my assemblies list. Also after disconnected, my test will still work. So it needs one time connection to the internet. I think it has something to do with the Verify() function.

Is there way to not have that first internet connection? I want to run my test on computers without internet connections. Im a noob with certificates so not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Why would following fail? PUBLIC_KEY.Equals(cert.GetPublicKeyString()).  The verify checks if certificate is readable (exists, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.verify?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Security_Cryptography_X509Certificates_X509Certificate2_Verify)   So the certificate is not null. it is readable, and the certificate passed signature encryption test.  Nothing checks the internet.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of [`X509Certificate2.Verify()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.verify?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Security_Cryptography_X509Certificates_X509Certificate2_Verify) it `Performs a X.509 chain validation using basic validation policy.`

(Basic) chain validation policy has many properties that tell how the chain should be built and how the certificates in the chain should be validated. In your case it is the default value of [`X509ChainPolicy.RevocationMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chainpolicy.revocationmode?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Security_Cryptography_X509Certificates_X509ChainPolicy_RevocationMode) property that is set to `Online`. This is the reason that X509Cerificate2.Verify() fails without internet connection. If you enable CAPI2 log in event logs you should see what has been done and that the revocation information was not available or intermediate CA certificate could not be fetched.

You could use [`X509Chain`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chain?view=netframework-4.7.2) class where it is possible to set your own validation policy and the `X509Chain.Build(X509Certificate2)` method to validate the certificate from dll. Then check `X509Chain.ChainElements` for error information as shown in the example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chain?view=netframework-4.7.2#examples)

Or you could use native [`WinVerifyTrust`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wintrust/nf-wintrust-winverifytrust) method. This method is used by windows to validate signature of a dll. You can find an example [here](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wintrust.winverifytrust). This is IMHO the correct way to check the signature of the dll (at least on windows).

Comment: This barely helps, because `X509Chain.Build` will fail without network connection with `RevocationOffline` status.

Comment: @Crypt32 You're right. If intermediate CAs are not already in store then it will fail on chain building. But there's always `WinVerifyTrust` option.

Comment: @Crypt32 yes I already tried that option. pepo I will get back to your solution of 'WinVerifyTrust'. I got also some other thing to do first. But I will investigate the 'WinVeryTrust' option.